# Склонение фамилий, оканчивающихся на "а"

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Фамилия Семика, носитель фамилии - мужчина. Склоняется ли такая фамилия. Вопрос важен, так как носитель фамилии не хочет, чтобы его фамилию склоняли.

Answer (score 1):

А чем он это мотивирует?
Желание носителя фамилии "не склонять" её в принципе имеет некоторый вес. Но нужна очень веская мотивировка. Обычно это происходит в тех случаях, когда при склонении возникает неблаглзвучие. Не буду примеры приводить, здесь я такого не вижу. Есть ещё вариант - объявить фамилию иноязычной, желательно - французской, с ударением на последнем слоге.

В остальных случаях и мужская, и женская фамилии на -а нормативно склоняются. Поэтому при написании документов (особенно долговременых: доверенностей, дипломов и т.п.) следует руководствоваться общими правилами и изменять фамилию по падежам.

Answer (score 0):

Такая фамилия склоняется, так как она оканчивается на гласный звук. Если бы фамилия оканчивалась на согласный звук, то при отношении к лицу мужского пола она бы не склонялась, а при отношении к лицу женского пола - склонялась.