# Склонение фамилии Викоброда

Tags: ономастика, склонение-фамилий

Фамилия **Викоброда** склоняется или нет?

Comment: Можно посмотреть ещё вопросы по ссылкам https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/21805/Склонение-фамилии-Иногда?rq=1
https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/420224/Склонение-фамилии-Купава?rq=1
https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/3331/Склонение-фамилий-оканчивающихся-на-а?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Если славянского происхождения, то склоняется (например, Щерба-Щербу и т. д.) Если французского, то не склоняется (например, Дюма). Эта фамилия скорее всего не французская, поэтому должна склоняться.